# Temperature dependent chemical potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, temperature, chemical-potential, fermi-energy

Chemical potential is determined by the number of electrons in the system and coincides with the Fermi energy at zero temperature. The chemical potential can shift as temperature changes if the density of states below and above the Fermi energy are different. However, this shift should be around $k\Delta T$, where $k$ is the Boltzmann constant.

Some materials exhibit Lifshitz transition (Fermi surface change) as temperature changes and the reported change in chemical potential is much higher than $k\Delta T$. How can it be possible? Is it due to some impurities that are activated after a certain temperature threshold?

Comment: I might be able to help.
You said: "The chemical potential can shift as temperature changes if the density of states below or above the Fermi energy"

In some circumstances $$ E_{F} = \mu $$

The volume of the fermi surface for a sphere is:

$$ V = 4 \pi r^{3} $$

The volume of an element of k-space is:

$$ V =( \frac{\pi}{L})^{3} $$

Consider the number of particles N

$$ k_{F} = (\frac{2\pi^{2}V}{N})^{1/3} $$

so because $$ \mu = E_{F} = \frac{\hbar^{2}k_{F}^{2}}{2m} $$

Then due to the change in density of states, can effect the fermi wave vector and therefore mu.

Comment: There was a paper on the arXiv today (https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.05088) which states without a reference that "generally, when increasing T, μ(T) will shift to the energy where the density of states is lower, so as to preserve the charge neutrality." I haven't found a source for this, though.